# Unir dos consultas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas y dos consultas para cada tabla

Una consulta es

```
SELECT DISTINCT CodContrato, FechaBaja, FechaFin
FROM Contrato
WHERE (FechaBaja != FechaFin)
AND (FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

y la otra

```
SELECT DISTINCT FechaFinProrroga
FROM DatoAuxiliarContrato
WHERE (FechaFinProrroga != '') AND (FechaFinProrroga BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

Ambas tablas tienen un dato en común que es `CodContrato`

Necesito hacer una consulta que unifique ambas querys, es decir,

```
SELECT DISTINCT CodContrato, FechaBaja, FechaFin, FechaFinProrroga
FROM Contrato, DatoAuxiliarContrato
WHERE ((FechaBaja != FechaFin)
        OR (FechaBaja != FechaFinProrroga))
AND (FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

Obviamente esto ultimo no funciona pero es para que veais lo que quiero
y no se como hacerlo
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Das poca información, sin explicaciones adicionales no sabremos si usar  `INNER JOIN` o `LEFT JOIN` lo cual también condicionaría el `WHERE`

Comment: agrega el modelo o como se relacionan , solo consulta es muy dificil ayudarte, si haber vamos la ultima consulta esta erronea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se ve claramente lo que intentas porque inicialmente defines consultas que cambia en la consulta unificada, pero entiendo que será algo parecido a esto. He cambiado también los OR por AND ya que entiendo que quieres que se cumplan todas las condiciones. Espero que a partir de esta consulta la puedas adecuar a lo que necesitas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CodContrato, FechaBaja, FechaFin, FechaFinProrroga
FROM Contrato INER JOIN DatoAuxiliarContrato ON Contrato.CodContrato=DatoAuxiliarContrato.CodContrato
WHERE FechaBaja != FechaFin AND FechaBaja != FechaFinProrroga AND FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco si las fechas que tienen el mismo nombre en ambas tablas deberían coincidir (supongo que sí), pero en caso de que sean distintas (una vez entiendas el ejemplo ya lo puedes adaptar) la consulta sería algo así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Contrato.CodContrato, Contrato.FechaBaja AS ContratoFechaBaja, Contrato.FechaFin AS ContratoFechaFin, DatoAuxiliarContrato.FechaBaja AS DatoAuxiliarContratoFechaBaja, DatoAuxiliarContrato.FechaFin AS DatoAuxiliarContratoFechaFin, DatoAuxiliarContrato.FechaFinProrroga
FROM Contrato INNER JOIN DatoAuxiliarContrato ON Contrato.CodContrato=DatoAuxiliarContrato.CodContrato 
WHERE (Contrato.FechaBaja != Contrato.FechaFin) AND (Contrato.FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')) 
AND ((DatoAuxiliarContrato.FechaFinProrroga != '') AND (DatoAuxiliarContrato.FechaFinProrroga BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59'))
```

Te aconsejo que eches un ojo a los distintos tipos de JOINS disponibles y utilices el que más se adecue a tu problema: [Tipos de JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Usando una subselect

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CodContrato, c.FechaBaja, c.FechaFin
FROM Contrato c
WHERE (c.FechaBaja != c.FechaFin OR c.FechaBaja 
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT FechaFinProrroga 
FROM DatoAuxiliarContrato WHERE CodContrato=c.CodContrato AND (FechaFinProrroga != '') AND (FechaFinProrroga BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')) )
AND (c.FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 1):

Probaste haciendo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    con.CodContrato,
    con.FechaBaja,
    con.FechaFin,
    dac.FechaFinProrroga
FROM
    Contrato AS con,
    DatoAuxiliarContrato AS dac
WHERE
    (
        con.FechaBaja != con.FechaFin 
        OR con.FechaBaja != dac.FechaFinProrroga
    )
    AND con.FechaBaja BETWEEN '20180101 00:00:00' AND '20181231 23:59:59';
```

ANSI SQL tiene una característica que se llama [EQUI JOIN](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-equi-join.php). Viendo la consulta que querías hacer, solo la modifique para que se adapte al estándar.

Espero que te sirva.